# Editing a content type using Content Type that doesn't exist in the Content Type Hub

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, content-type

We deployed some Site Collections using templates that weren't linked with the Content Types on our Content Type Hub, in fact, we have never really used the ct hub. All our Site collections have a specific set of content types that don't exist on the Content Type Hub.

Now we are faced with the task of having to update the Content Type descriptions. Is there any way of creating these content types on our Content Type Hub and have them update on the Site Collections?

I have already created/published some new content types to see that things are coming through as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can connect existing content types to the ones in CT Hub. Best way forward for you would be to create an PowerShell script to update the content types across your web application.